# AxWindowsMediaPLayer: Pause video at last frame using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have designed a Winform App for Microsoft Surface Hub (touch device).

**Summary:**

1. **Form 1** is the **Introduction** Form which plays a single video (axWindowsMediaPlayer) in loop until a user interrupts the application.
2. If a user interrupts the application, the `axWindowsMediaPlayer` stops playing and **Form 2** i.e. the **Menu** Form is brought to front using `this.BringToFront()`. **Form 2** displays `.swf` file. Form 2 contains various options to choose from.
3. Upon choosing an option from Form 2, the user is redirected to **Form 3** which can either be a `axWindowsMediaPlayer` or `.swf` depending upon the user's choice. As of now there are **8** `media` files and **2** `.swf` files.
4. The user can switch to next/previous option from the current option. **NOTE:** No automatic switching is enabled even after the end of media.

**NOTE:** I switch between my forms using `sendToBack()` and `BringToFront()`

**What happens** while playing the `axWindowsMediaPlayer` file is that after the media has ended, it displays a black screen.

**What I want** is my application should capture the last frame and display that frame after the media has ended instead of the black screen. Or **Pause** the media on reaching the last frame.

How do I achieve this using **C#**

**P.S:** I have seen a score of questions on this, but almost all has no accepted answer and none of the technique's seems to be working

**Edit 1:** I tried using

> axWindowsMediaPlayer.currentMedia.duration

and a few more things which didn't helped my case.